# Connection cannot be reassociated because child objects are still open

Tags: java, oracle, websphere

Getting following exception frequently during normal usage from my java application hosted on IBM WebSphere server.

```
     : DSRA9420E: Connection cannot be reassociated because child objects are still open.
Exception from createCallableStatement(String query,int resultSetType,int resultSetConcurrency)
java.sql.SQLException: DSRA9420E: Connection cannot be reassociated because child objects are still open.

    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.AdapterUtil.toSQLException(AdapterUtil.java:1699)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcConnection.activate(WSJdbcConnection.java:2933)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcConnection.prepareCall(WSJdbcConnection.java:2652)
    at dataInterface.CrossRefDbConnectionProvider.createCallableStatement(CrossRefDbConnectionProvider.java:154)
    at dataInterface.CrossRefDbExecutionHelper.preparedCall(CrossRefDbExecutionHelper.java:168)
    at Schneider.Competitor.doPost(Competitor.java:211)

    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1230)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:779)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:478)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1071)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:87)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:914)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)

    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:459)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:526)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:312)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:88)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)

    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1864)
Caused by: com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.exceptions.DataStoreAdapterException: DSRA9420E: Connection cannot be reassociated because child objects are still open.
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.AdapterUtil.createDataStoreAdapterException(AdapterUtil.java:441)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcConnection.reassociate(WSJdbcConnection.java:3045)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.WSRdbManagedConnectionImpl.associateConnection(WSRdbManagedConnectionImpl.java:5141)
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.MCWrapper.associateConnection(MCWrapper.java:2554)
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.ConnectionManager.reassociateConnectionHandle(ConnectionManager.java:2949)
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.ConnectionManager.associateConnection(ConnectionManager.java:2931)
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.ConnectionManager.associateConnection(ConnectionManager.java:2813)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsad
```

Please help me to find the root cause this exception and how can i fix that

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post some details of your dataInterface layer?   Are you caching the connection handle or are you doing get-use-close each time?

Answer (score 1):

Is the application accessing a JDBC connection and/or the resources obtained from it (statements, result sets,...) from multiple threads?  Given the stack, that's the only explanation I can think of for how to get into this state.  If so, that sort of usage isn't supported by JDBC and the application would need to be updated to avoid using a connection and its statements, result sets, ... and so on across different threads.