# open liberty and ConnectionManager

Tags: open-liberty

I'm new on Open Liberty and I need to maintain a legacy app

I have on this app logs the following error:

```
The ConnectionManager was unable to associate Connection com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcConnection@3b05f444 with ManagedConnection 
WSRdbManagedConnectionImpl@67538473 for resource jdbc/AppDs. Received exception: com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.exceptions.DataStoreAdapterException: 
DSRA9420E: Connection cannot be reassociated because child objects are still open.
```

I'm not sure from to start on this.

I have already searched [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40902962/connection-cannot-be-reassociated-because-child-objects-are-still-open)

But the code that is shown on logs is based on spring and it couldn't leak connections.

The app uses spring and ehcache.

Please, can someone to provide some guidance?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the Open Liberty source, that error is raised from a single place in the code, in response to the error condition that a JDBC Connection still has open child JDBC resources (such as Statement, PreparedStatement, ...) associated with it, at a point where it is being asked to reassociate the connection handle across transaction boundaries.  Looking at the single caller of that code, it appears that the dissociate method (which closes these same JDBC resources) would have been invoked only a few lines earlier, suggesting that the only way for you to reach the state where the error occurs is if other code were simultaneously using the connection from another thread.  To help confirm if this is the case, you could try enabling Liberty trace (via server.xml config) of

```
<logging traceSpecification="*=info:RRA=all"/>
```

while reproducing the error and post it somewhere accessible to look at.